# Redundant code in getters and setters

Tags: c#, properties, dry, getter-setter

I have a class that needs to call a method `NotifyPropertyChanged` when any of its properties are changed. What I've seen in examples is something like:

```
private string property1_;
public string Property1
{
    get { return property1_; }
    set { property1_ = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
}
private string property2_;
public string Property2
{
    get { return property2_; }
    set { property2_ = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
}
// .......
```

Is this really the idiomatic way to do it? It requires several lines of boilerplate for every property I want to add. Moreover, if I want to change the name of the property and field, I would need to change 4 different things. It seems like a violation of DRY.

Comment: There are MVVM frameworks that can make this DRY, like MVVM Light https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try using an AOP framework to implement your `INotifyPropertyChanged`. My personal favourite for this example is called [Fody.](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged)

You would write the class like this...

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class Foo
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Fody works by rewriting your dll after MsBuild is done with it, to implement your INPC code.

Comment: Accepted this answer because it was the one I ended up using.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is the idiomatic way to raise `PropertyChanged`. There's no easy way around it, since the setter needs an additional method call and the only way to do that is with a full property and backing field.

It actually used to be worse, as before .NET 4.5 you had to pass the property name as a string to "NotifyPropertyChanged", so changing the name is actually quite a bit easier now.

That said, there are frameworks (MVVMLight, Caliburn.Micro) that will inject the event raise for you if you choose to use them. Of course, they are just giving you a little syntatic sugar, and the end result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

PostSharp (https://www.postsharp.net/model/inotifypropertychanged) is another compile-time option for automatically generating INotifyPropertyChanged event raising that uses attributes to indicate methods for which this should be done.